# One column lost after using SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used SimpleImputer on some dataframe. The no. of columns in the imputed dataframe is less than the original dataframe.

`cat_cols` is a list of categorical columns of DataFrame `X_valid` and has 43 elements.

i.e original DataFrame:

```
X_valid[cat_cols]
```

has 146 rows × 43 columns

imputed DataFrame:

```
cat_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
pd.DataFrame(cat_imputer.fit_transform(X_valid[cat_cols]))
```

has 146 rows × 42 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of your columns was entirely missing values?  From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html):

> **Notes**
>
> Columns which only contained missing values at `fit` are discarded upon `transform` if `strategy` is not `"constant"`.

and (possibly more generally)

> **`statistics_` : *array of shape (n_features,)***
>
> The imputation fill value for each feature. Computing statistics can result in `np.nan` values. During `transform`, features corresponding to `np.nan` statistics will be discarded.

(so `statistics_` gives a good way to identify those features).